# SVN: "repository moved permantly" error when adding a new folder under root

Tags: svn

I am having a strange problem with SVN:
SVN is located in `http://local/svn` (linux + apache), where I have several repos:
`http://local/svn/repo1`, `http://local/svn/repo2` etc

My SVN client is in Windows and the folder is `c:\mysvn`.

When I commiting an existing sub-folder (e.g. `http://local/svn/repo1/folder1`), everything works OK!

When I add and try to commit a new sub-folder in Windows (e.g. `c:\mysvn\repo1\folder2`) I get the error:

"Repository moved permantly to `http://local/svn/repo1`; please relocate"

When I try to relocate, I get the same error.

This happens to all repos I have. It didn't happen before, but I can not recall any recent changes on the CentOS server.

Here is my `/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf`

```
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /var/www/svn

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion repos"
    AuthUserFile /etc/svn-users
    Require valid-user   
</Location>
```

And the access_log file from apache:

```
192.168.2.15 - - [21/Nov/2013:11:14:10 +0200] "OPTIONS /svn/archives HTTP/1.1" 401 482 "-" "SVN/1.8.4 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.2 TortoiseSVN-1.8.3.24901"
192.168.2.15 - gary [21/Nov/2013:11:14:10 +0200] "OPTIONS /svn/archives HTTP/1.1" 301 325 "-" "SVN/1.8.4 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.2 TortoiseSVN-1.8.3.24901"
192.168.2.15 - gary [21/Nov/2013:11:14:10 +0200] "PROPFIND /svn/archives HTTP/1.1" 301 325 "-" "SVN/1.8.4 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.2 TortoiseSVN-1.8.3.24901"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a workaround, based on this message

http://tigris-scm.10930.n7.nabble.com/TortoiseSVN-1-4-0-Build-7195-fails-when-Apache-sends-301-Redirect-td39856.html

I added the following line in `subversion.conf`

`BrowserMatch "TortoiseSVN" redirect-carefully`